# Is it possible to create digital signature with specific p, q, e values by using OpenSSL?

Tags: rsa, signature, openssl

I'm trying to create the digital signature by using these parameters and RSA algorithm:

- p = 645353605880701501120167331073
- q = 350784310265709643169455170929
- e = 19
- message = "G’day mate! As we are using a publicly available free WiFi network, our communication may be intercepted by cyber attackers. Therefore, we need to learn and apply cryptography techniques in our future communications."

I assume that I need to use OpenSSL to create the signature. However, I have no idea why the value of p, q, and e are given...
If I use OpenSSL, maybe I don't need to use these values, and we can generate RSA public/private key automatically.
Should I use OpenSSL to create a digital signature, or do I need to compute it manually? Are there any other tools that I could use to get the result?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The public modulus $n=pq$ obtained from the question is 198-bit. That  size is much too short to be secure.

Also it's too short for the most common standard RSA signature formats [RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5](https://pkcs1.grieu.fr/#%5B%7B%22num%22:90,%22gen%22:0%7D,%7B%22name%22:%22XYZ%22%7D,118,721,null%5D) and [RSASSA-PSS](https://pkcs1.grieu.fr/#%5B%7B%22num%22:78,%22gen%22:0%7D,%7B%22name%22:%22XYZ%22%7D,118,314,null%5D), even with a 128-bit hash.

See [Dave Thomson's comment](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/219243?noredirect=1) for other padding formats that could still be usable.

Comment: OpenSSL also supports X9.31 padding which can be as little as 2 bytes, and 'no' padding which if you allow (room for at least) one zero byte is effectively 'block type 0' from PKCS1-v1; these would allow a 160-bit hash, of which I believe RIPEMD160 is not broken. These paddings are no longer standard and not secure, but RSA-198 is already broken as you say so additional weakness doesn't really matter.

Answer (score -1):

I think you can do that in theory but I'm not sure of the actual specifics on how to do that. It's generally not advised to generate your own P & Q unless you have taken due care in generating them.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).